# How can I execute a *.sql script on android programmatically?

Tags: android, sqlite

How can I execute a *.sql script on android programmatically?
The script is located at /assert folder. My phone is not rooted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open("SQLScript.sql");
String sql= convertStreamToString(is);

public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)
            throws IOException {
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        char[] buffer = new char[2048];
        try {
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,
                    "UTF-8"));
            int n;
            while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        String text = writer.toString();
        return text;
}


SQLiteDatabase db;
db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDatabase.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null );
db.execSQL(sql);
```

Comment: This just executes the first sql statment.
From documentation of execSQL, "Execute a single SQL statement that does not return any data."

Comment: Not only that, but it explicitly states it now [SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(sql)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#execSQL(java.lang.String)): "`@param` `sql` the SQL statement to be executed. Multiple statements separated by semicolons are not supported."